# How to generate the pairwise win probability matrix according to the win probability of each competitor?

Tags: probability, game-theory, python, empirical-processes

For example, I have the win probability vector `p = [0.2, 0.5, 0.8]` which means the first player wins with a probability of 0.2 against a random player, the player 2 wins with a probability of 0.5 against a random player and so on.

I want to generate a pairwise matrix having each 1vs1 probabilities. I wrote this formula:

$$P(\textrm{A wins against B}) = \frac{P(\textrm{A wins}) \cdot (1 - P(\textrm{B wins}))}{P(\textrm{A wins}) \cdot (1 - P(\textrm{B wins})) + (1 - P(\textrm{A wins})) \cdot P(\textrm{B wins})}$$

So, to generate the matrix, we can use this formula:

$$M_{ij} = \frac{p_i \cdot (1 - p_j)}{p_i \cdot (1 - p_j) + (1 - p_i) \cdot p_j}$$

with `p` the win prob vector and `M` the matrix I want to generate.

**My question is: what is the right formula?**

Because when I empirically try to "prove" the formula, I get results near the expected result (but not exact).

Here the python code of the proof:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import random

def getRandomFloat(min=0.0, max=1.0, decimalMax=2):
    return round(random.uniform(min, max), decimalMax)
def truncateFloat(f, n=2):
    '''Truncates/pads a float f to n decimal places without rounding'''
    s = '{}'.format(f)
    if 'e' in s or 'E' in s:
        return float('{0:.{1}f}'.format(f, n))
    i, p, d = s.partition('.')
    return float('.'.join([i, (d+'0'*n)[:n]]))

def generate_pairwise_win_prob(win_prob, float_precision=None):
    # We create the pairwise win probability (`p_win_prob`):
    p_win_prob = np.zeros((len(win_prob), len(win_prob)))
    w = win_prob
    for i in range(len(win_prob)):
        for j in range(i, len(win_prob)):
            # p_win_prob[i, j] = 1 / (1 + np.exp(w[j] - w[i])) # The Bradley-Terry-Luce model doesn't work
            p_win_prob[i, j] = (w[i] * (1 - w[j])) / (w[i] * (1 - w[j]) + (1 - w[i]) * w[j])
            if float_precision is not None:
                p_win_prob[i, j] = truncateFloat(p_win_prob[i, j], float_precision)
            p_win_prob[j, i] = 1 - p_win_prob[i,j]
    return p_win_prob

def pwp_empirical_proof(win_prob, draw_prob_interval=None):
    p_win_prob = generate_pairwise_win_prob(win_prob)
    victories = [0] * len(win_prob)
    defeats = [0] * len(win_prob)
    for i in range(100000):
        a, b = random.sample(range(len(win_prob)), 2)
        result = match(a, b, p_win_prob, draw_prob_interval=draw_prob_interval)
        if result != 0:
            if result == 1:
                victories[a] += 1
                defeats[b] += 1
            else:
                victories[b] += 1
                defeats[a] += 1
    predicted_win_prob = []
    for i in range(len(win_prob)):
        current = victories[i] / (victories[i] + defeats[i])
        current = truncateFloat(current, 2)
        predicted_win_prob.append(current)
    print("win_prob: " + str(win_prob))
    print("predicted_win_prob: " + str(predicted_win_prob))
    print()

# We define the function that will give the result of a match:
def match(i, j, p_win_prob, draw_prob_interval=None): # draw a comparision from the model
    assert i != j
    rdf = getRandomFloat()
    if draw_prob_interval is not None and abs(p_win_prob[i, j] - rdf) <= draw_prob_interval:
        return 0 # draw
    elif rdf < p_win_prob[i,j]:
        return 1 # i beats j
    else:
        return -1 # j beats i

pwp_empirical_proof([0.2, 0.5, 0.8])
```

And I get:

```
win_prob: [0.2, 0.5, 0.8]
predicted_win_prob: [0.12, 0.49, 0.87]
```

Comment: Something else confusing to me, the mean of the p vector need to be 0.5? Maybe my problem is not the formula but the win prob vector p...

Comment: You seem to be treating the events that A wins and that B loses as independent, which makes no sense when A plays agains B.  In fact, there is insufficient information given to calculate the probabilities you want to compute.  It is possible that A wins against a random player with probability $.2$, C wins against a random player with probability $.8$, and A wins against C with probability $.7$, say.

Comment: @saulspatz do you mean we cannot generate the matrix?

Comment: There is indeed a problem with your input win probability vector. There are conditions it must satisfy. For example, you can't allow $[1,1,1]$ which would say everyone wins every time. (I haven't thought about what those conditions are.)

Comment: Yes, you can't solve this problem without more information.  Perhaps A and C are tennis players, where A loses $80\%$ of his games and $C$ wins $80\%$ of his games.  You might think than $C$ is very likely to beat A, but no, C has trouble playing against left-handed players, and is fortunate that there are few left-handed players in the league.  Unfortunately for C, A is left-handed.

Comment: @saulspatz but if I assume that each player is very consistent. For example, the skill of a player ONLY depends on the number of years he has been training. So with this assumption, given the win prob, we can calculate the 1vs1 win prob no?

Comment: @EthanBolker I agree, intuitively I respect the rule $\frac{\sum_{i = 1}^{|p|} p_i}{|p|} = 0.5$ but can't find something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more an extended comment than an answer, party because, as I indicated in my comments, I don't think it is possible to answer the question as given.

As I said, we need more information; the player's winning percentage against competitors at large doesn't determine his probability of beating a particular opponent, even if we know the opponent's winning percentage.

You can make other assumptions to try to compute the probability of A beating B, but you must make sure that it is consistent.  The formula you suggest $$P_{AB}=\frac{P_A(1-P_B)}{P_A(1-P_B)+P_B(1-P_A)}$$ (where $P_{AB}$ is the probability that A beats B,) has the property that $P_{AB}+P_{BA}=1$ if $P_{BA}$ is computed according to  the analogous formula, which is mandatory if there are no ties.

However, if the players are $A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$, we also need, for example,

$$P_{A_1}=P_{A_1A_2}+P_{A_1A_3}+\cdots+P_{A_1A_n}\tag1$$ if $A_1$ is equally likely to play any of the other players.  Does your formula guarantee this?  I doubt it.

We might try to rectify this with a formula like $$P_{A_kA_j}=P_k\frac{P_{A_j}}{\sum_{m\neq k}P_{A_m}}$$

With this definition, equation $(1)$ would be satisfied, but we would no longer have $P_{AB}+P_{BA}=1$.

In short, I can't think of a formula, at least not off the top of my head, that would guarantee consistency of the results.  Also, it seems to me that finding such a formula, if one exists, would require making entirely unrealistic assumptions about the problem.

Comment: Thank you @saulspatz, I'll accept your answer that it's impossible. But I wait a few days, in case someone has a miraculous idea.